# Copy command not working in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am unable to run the COPY command in cassandra. Here is the ColumnFamily that I am using

```
CREATE TABLE ap_perf_sample_data_tbl(
ap_mac varchar,
ap_proto int,
stime int,
ap_active_status int,
bytes_from_dev int,
bytes_to_dev int,
location_id int,
num_assocs int,
num_data_pkts int,
num_retry_pkts int,
throughput_from_ap int,
throughput_to_ap int,
throughput_total_ap int,
time_spent_on_channel int,
time_util_by_ap int,
PRIMARY KEY ((ap_mac, ap_proto), stime)
```

I'm trying to use the COPY command in cqlsh as follows:

> cqlsh:performance_data> **copy ap_perf_sample_data_tbl**  (ap_mac,
>   ap_proto , stime, location_id, num_data_pkts, num_retry_pkts,
>   num_assocs, time_util_by_ap, time_spent_on_channel, throughput_to_ap,
>   throughput_from_ap, throughput_total_ap, bytes_to_dev, bytes_from_dev
>   ,ap_active_status) from '**/tmp/top'**; 
> **Bad Request: Invalid
>   STRING constant (1) for ap_proto of type int** 
> Aborting import
>   at record #0 (line 1). 
>   Previously-inserted values still
>   present.
>  0 rows imported in 0.008 seconds.
>   cqlsh:performance_data>
>
> Contents of "/tmp/top"

---

> 00:00:01:00:01:00,1,1359532800,1,6002166,312781,10,845100,9045000,259143,241011,52835,186318,5413799,10
>   00:00:02:00:02:00,1,1359532800,2,6002166,312781,10,845100,9045000,259143,241011,52835,186318,5413799,10
>   00:00:03:00:03:00,1,1359532800,3,6002166,312781,10,845100,9045000,259143,241011,52835,186318,5413799,10
>   00:00:04:00:04:00,1,1359532800,4,6002166,312781,10,845100,9045000,259143,241011,52835,186318,5413799,10

---

Following is the version information.

> [root@localhost ~]# cqlsh  Connected to Test Cluster at
>   localhost:9160. [cqlsh 2.3.0 | Cassandra 1.2.2 | CQL spec 3.0.0 |
>   Thrift protocol 19.35.0] Use HELP for help.

Any clues as to why this may happen will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Bug#5305 filed for this issue in 1.2.2 Cassandra.