# Cassandra how to add clustering key in table?

Tags: cassandra, cql3

There is a table in cassandra

```
create table test_moments(id Text, title Text, sort int, PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

How add clustering key in column "sort". Not re-creating the table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between partition key, composite key and clustering key in Cassandra?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949676/difference-between-partition-key-composite-key-and-clustering-key-in-cassandra)

Comment: no.I want to add a key for sorting into an existing table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem is the on-disk data structure. Clustering key directly dictates how data is sorted and serialized to disk (and then searched), so what you're asking is not possible.

The only way is to "migrate" the data to another table. Depending on your data, if you have a lot of records you could encounter some timeout error during the queries, so be prepared to tweak your migration with some useful techniques such as the COPY command or the TOKEN function.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24298982) SO question also.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is add it as the second part of the PRIMARY KEY to make it a composite key

```
create table test_moments(id Text, title Text, sort int, PRIMARY KEY(id, sort));
```

Comment: Not re-creating the table

Comment: Its not possible. Clustering key regards the sorting of data, and this sorting is done on write, not on read. You need to re-create the table